# Symfony2 app/console cache:clear throws RuntimeException ($_SESSION is set)

Tags: symfony, session, symfony-2.6, symfony-console

for some reasons I get an error each time I try to execute `app/console cache:clear`

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set).

Unfortunately I dind' find any useful info. I already checked `php -i | grep session` settings in `php.ini` but those seems to be ok

```
session.auto_start => Off
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?!

**P.S.** My current "dirty workaround" is just `rm -rf app/cache/prod/*` but

Comment: `sudo rm -rf app/cache/*;sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/`

Comment: What do you have if you run php app/check.php ? http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right :

Try to set up permissions again on your app/cache (and app/log again), following instructions on this page, below "Setting up permision" : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

it involves to delete the whole content of these folders before setting up the permisions

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. I set `app/cache` and its all contens to 777 ... but no success. Still the same error-message